# Get old reddit submissions with PRAW

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I discovered [PRAW](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) this morning and got the idea to track the most used words in a subreddit over time. To do this, I first need to get the submissions with this line:

```
new_posts = list(reddit.subreddit('AnySubreddit').new(limit=1000))
```

The issue is that I only get the 1000 newest posts even if I set the limit to 5000 for example.

I know it's no longer possible to get submissions by date but is it possible to get more than the 1000 newest submissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nobody replied, I'm answering my own question if it can help someone.

Unfortunately, it's not possible with the Reddit API and PRAW, but if you really want to do this, you can use [pushshift](https://pushshift.io/) and [PSAW](https://psaw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).